# Возведение в степень на Intel x86

Tags: ассемблер

Мне надо реализовать функцию возведения в степень на архитектуре Intel x86.

Вот мой неправильный вариант:

```
power:
    test %edx, %edx
    jz return1
    mov %eax, %ebx
    for:
        imul %ebx, %eax
        dec %edx
        test %edx, %edx
        jz return
        jmp for
    return:
        mov %eax, %eax
        ret
    return1:
        mov $1, %eax
        ret
```

Никак не могу понять в чем у меня ошибка...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел проблему. Правильный вариант будет такой:

```
power:
    test %edx, %edx
    jz return1
    mov %eax, %ebx
    for:
        dec %edx
        test %edx, %edx
        jz return

        imul %ebx, %eax
        jmp for
    return:
        mov %eax, %eax
        ret
    return1:
        mov $1, %eax
        ret
```

Comment: И в чем же разница, если не секрет?

Comment: Что-то вот эта конструкция вызывает сомнения в плане того, что она ничего не делает: `mov %eax, %eax`

Comment: Извиняюсь. Случайно скопировал из буффера старое решение и быстро убежал на работу, не посмотрев.

Answer (score 2):

Сделал чуть короче

```
power:
mov %eax, %ebx
for:
    dec %edx
    test %edx, %edx
    jz return

    imul %ebx, %eax
    jmp for
return:
     ret
```

Answer (score 0):

```
power:
    test %edx, %edx
    jz ifnull
    mov %eax, %ebx
    for:
        dec %edx
        test %edx, %edx
        jz returnrez
        imul %ebx, %eax
        jmp for

    ifnull:
        mov $1, %eax
    returnrez:
    ret
```